# Add two multidimensional PHP associative array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Question about PHP:

To create a chart with ChartJS, I need to retrieve a given table. I managed to get 2 tables $ data and $ data1 (because 2 separate tables) and I try to add them. (No common key between the two tables

```
$select = $bdd->prepare("SELECT MONTH(DateProd) as Mois, SUM(TempsProd*nbGabarit) as Heure FROM impression
                            GROUP BY MONTH(DateProd)
                            ");
$select->execute();

$row = $select->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $data[] = $row;


$select2 = $bdd->prepare("SELECT MONTH(DateRD) as Mois, SUM(TempsRD) as Heure FROM recherche_dev
                            GROUP BY MONTH(DateRD)");
$select2->execute();
$data1 = array();
$row2 = $select2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $data1[] = $row2;
```

Here is the example data of $data an array with a print_r:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array ([Month] => 8 [Time] => 181.37)
  [1] => Array ([Month] => 9 [Time] => 753.39)
  [2] => Array ([Month] => 10 [Time] => 1292.25)
  [3] => Array ([Month] => 11 [Time] => 350.61)
)
```

Here is the example data of $data1 an array with a print_r:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array ([Month] => 11 [Time] => 25.50)

)
```

I try to merge $data and $data1 the "Time" to obtain a single array like this :.

```
Array (
  [0] => Array ([Month] => 8 [Time] => 181.37)
  [1] => Array ([Month] => 9 [Time] => 753.39)
  [2] => Array ([Month] => 10 [Time] => 1292.25)
  [3] => Array ([Month] => 11 [Time] => 376.11) // result of $data[3][Time] + $data1[0][Time] because $data[3][Month] = $data1[0][Month]
)
```

If you have any ideas I am interested I have been trying for 3 days

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand as it's currently written. Please edit your question and elaborate a bit about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Please show us two sample tables, the code you have written so far, and the result you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry if i was unclear, i have edit my post with more explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this solves your problem and I think the algorithm can be further improved.

```
$array1 = [
    0 => ['Month' => 8, 'Time' => 181.37],
    1 => ['Month' => 9, 'Time' => 753.39],
    2 => ['Month' => 10, 'Time' => 1292.25],
    3 => ['Month' => 11, 'Time' => 350.61],
];

$array2 = [
    0 => ['Month' => 11, 'Time' => 25.50],
];

$data = array_merge($array1, $array2);

$result = [];
$markMonth = [];
foreach ($data as $key =>  $datum) {
    if (false === array_search($datum['Month'], $markMonth)) {
        $filter = array_filter($data, function($iterator) use (&$markMonth, $datum) {
            if ($iterator['Month'] === $datum['Month']) {
                if (false === array_search($iterator['Month'], $markMonth)) {
                    $markMonth[] = $iterator['Month'];
                }

                return $iterator;
            }
        });

        if (count($filter) > 1) {
            $preResultValue = [$key => ['Month' => $filter[$key]['Month'], 'Time' => 0]];
            foreach ($filter as $value) {
                $preResultValue[$key]['Time'] += $value['Time'];
            }

            $result[] = $preResultValue[$key];
        } else {
            $result[] = $filter[$key];
        }
    } 
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Pablo Moreno Martin your algorithm solve my problem thanks. Now i will take the time to good understand it for the future.

Comment: Basically I make a merge of the 2 arrays, then I go through the resulting array, in each iteration I check that the given month did not appear in a previous iteration, if it meets the check I look for all the occurrences of this month in the array that I am iterating, these occurrences I put them in a temporary array, add all the time values of this temporary array, add it to the month and add to the array that will have my final result.

Answer (score 0):

Use [UNION DISTINCT](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/sql-union.php)

```
    $sql  = "SELECT MONTH(DateProd) as Mois,
                    SUM(TempsProd*nbGabarit) as Heure ";

    $sql .= "FROM impression ";
    $sql .= "GROUP BY Mois ";

    $sql .= "UNION DISTINCT ";

    $sql .= "SELECT MONTH(DateRD) as Mois,
                    SUM(TempsRD) as Heure ";

    $sql .= "FROM recherche_dev ";
    $sql .= "GROUP BY Mois ";


    $select = $bdd->prepare($sql);
    $select->execute();

    $row    = $select->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $data[] = $row;
```